# Teams Online Sessions API's

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Dears, Here are some issues regarding using Teams online sessions through Ms. graph api:

1- We could not launch the virtual classrooms using Firefox browsers,  for windows OS user will have the option to use Microsoft edge browser, however for Mac OS user will stuck and will not be able to join unless using the chrome browser

2- After launching the virtual classrooms by the organizer for the first time, teams will ask the user to add a name which is incorrect behavior, however user have the option to sign in but the link is in the bottom and not clear

3- Connecting team app/web is too slow and takes too long time before connecting ( around 3 minutes )

4- "Sign in as trial" message is appearing for the users

5- students can enter any name on join screen, which is not appropriate

6- Video resolution is too bad, too slow, there is a lag around 1.5 minute different between users

7- if organizer mute any student, there is no option to unmute

8- sharing screens by organizer does work properly

9- Organizer could not end the virtual classrooms on teams

10- Organizer does not have the option to prevent sharing screen,  open/close camera

when using teams app instead of web:

1- there is no option to sign in when launch the meeting while organizer is logged out from teams app, will only have the option to add a name

2- Participants list is displaying after too long time

3- If there are two different users, one of them is using the app and other one using teams on web, all chat conversations using the web will be sent by name of user on teams app

plus same above issues exist on the app

can you please advice!

Comment: This is not a developer question. This is more a question for the product team who own the Teams user experience. There appears to be info here on how to get support for this type of feedback https://support.office.com/en-us/Teams

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out with your feedback about Teams for Education. I"m Angela Chin, Lead Program Manager for Teams for Education.

I've passed your feedback back to our engineer team.  We're working on many of these and are constantly pushing improvements to the Teams experience.

For hands on support for any distance learning challenges you may be facing with Teams, please join our Remote Learning Community: https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR2c4qMfVhOdCngYnH0quosFUNUw1SjdQQ1FBSEw0WUlPTkcyOEVXUEFMTSQlQCN0PWcu

Members of the Microsoft Education engineering teams are chatting live with educators to take feedback, help with support questions and share tips.